# Better Understanding Using Google Places Api

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I want to develop an application in which i want to display restaurants nearby the user.

Say for example i want to display name and address of restaurants located within 3km related to current location of the android device..

I have done alot of reading online and found different links here on stackoverflow.com
I am aware that I must use the **GOOGLE PLACES API**, I found this link to this blog on this site [Introducing the Google Places API](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI)

My problem is how to use android/Java to:
1. Send a request to this url : "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=MYAPIKEY"
2. Then parse the XML or JSON results from this request and display them in a list for the user to see.

Thank you in advance for anyone that can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look at some online tutorials like for instance
http://blog.brianbuikema.com/2010/08/android-development-part-1-using-googles-places-api-to-develop-compelling-location-based-mobile-applications/

Comment: I have checked this one out before. I will look at it again, test it out and I will come back with specific questions. I am aware that google places api is now open to the public and there is no need for the client Id, and adsense as it says in this tutorial.

thanks for your response and help